# Using Facebook Android SDK (API-key)

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying the Facebook Android SDK, but I don't know where to insert my API-key.

The error I get when trying to log in using the Example-app is: 
`"Login Failed: android_key_not_configured"` 
where do I find this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you read through this ?
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

here is from one of the examples :

```
public class Example extends Activity {

    // Your Facebook Application ID must be set before running this example
    // See http://www.facebook.com/developers/createapp.php
    public static final String APP_ID = "175729095772478";
```

Comment: I think that error occurs when you don't do the "setup single sign on" part in the README at the site Alex pointed to: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Yes I did. I followed it step by step, but I still get the error.

Comment: Ok. I posted my comment before I saw yours.

Comment: I'll try doing the "single sign on".